# Orientation of parametrization

Tags: vector-analysis, parametrization

[image]

[image]

This is what I have so far for part (a). I am not entirely sure if this is how I should approach this or where to go from this point.

Comment: After calculating the normal vector for each point, evaluate in some convenient place, and check out the direction of the vector. This will determine the orientation this parametrization gives. There are only two possible, so by choosing an "easy" point to analyze, you'll be able to decide if it coincides with the one given to you or not.

Comment: $T_u\times T_v$ is a **vector**, but you've written it as a scalar on your last line. (Look back at your penultimate line: you left off $\hat{j}$ and $\hat{k}$.) You need to check whether that vector, normalized to have unit length, is the same thing as the normal vector evaluated at the parametrization.

Comment: you have mapped $z$ to $\hat j$ and $y$ to $\hat k$  I am not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T_u =\frac {\partial}{\partial u} (u \cos v, u^2, u\sin v) = (\cos x, 2u, \sin x)\\
T_v = \frac {\partial}{\partial v} (u \cos v, u^2, u\sin v) = (-u\sin v, 0, u\cos v)\\
T_u\times T_v = (2u^2\cos v, -u, 2u^2 \sin v) = u(2x, -1, 2z)$

Which is the reverse of the desired orientation.

$\iint F\cdot dS\\
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 (0, u^2,u^2\sin v\cos v)\cdot (-2u^2\cos v, u, -2u\sin v)\ du\ dv\\
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 u^3 - 2u^3\sin^2 v\cos v \ du\ dv\\
$

And I will let you take if from here.